# Can someone identify the source this story which mentions about relativity of time

Tags: identification-request, time

The below text is a rough outline of a story from Hindu Purana. But I don't know the exact story and the source text of that story. My interest in that story is that, it gives us an hint about relative nature of "Time" which was an "Unthinkable concept" before the introduction of relativity theory.

**Outline of story**:

A King from earth wanted to marry most perfect women in the world, Since he was not able find any perfect match from earth, he traveled to Deva-Loka and tried to Meet King Indra.
At the time he asked for an appointment, the King Indra was watching in a Song/Dance performance. So, Indra asked him to wait for some time till the performance finishes.

After some time, Indra came and met our king who came from earth. They discussed something ( I don't remember those ), and after that the King returned to earth.

When the King reached earth, He faced a new problem.
That is, while we was waiting for the performance to finish in Deva-loka, Many hundred years got passed here in Earth and everything changed. it is because, the Time runs slower in Deva-Loka the scale is different

Notably, the size of people changed drastically . People had became smaller in size.

Then some sage reduced the size of the king through using his magical powers,  and finally, he married one girl .

---

This is the story.
Can anybody remember the exact story and its reference ?

Comment: It appears like travel of  Ravati and her father Kakudmi to Brahma loka.  Later she was married to  Balarama.( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi  )@harish2704

Comment: it seems not to be Indra's devaloka..it has to be some other higher loka..bcz 1day&night of Devaloka is equal to just 1 human year...and I don't think dance performance would last for 100s deva days....also any other stories is duplicate q, pls remove that..

Comment: @srimannarayanakv : Thanks!! This is the exact story I was searching for.

Comment: @YDS: You are right. I only had a very rough outline about that story and it was wrong too. I understand that now.

Answer (score 2):

[Kakudmi](https://www.booksfact.com/puranas/theory-of-relativity-time-travel-in-bhagavata-purana-tripura-rahasya.html) was a descendant of the Sun Dynasty (Suryavansha).

Kakudmi’s daughter Revati was so beautiful and so accomplished that when she reached a marriageable age, Kakudmi, thinking no one upon earth was worthy of her, [went to the Creator himself, Lord Brahma](http://bhagavata.org/canto9/chapter3.html), to seek his advice about a suitable husband for his daughter.

When they arrived, Brahma was listening to a musical performance by the Gandharvas, so they waited patiently until the performance was finished. Then, Kakudmi bowed humbly, made his request and presented his shortlist of candidates. Brahma laughed loudly, and explained that time runs differently on different planes of existence, and that during the short time they had waited in Brahma-loka to see him, 27 chaturyugas (a cycle of four yugas, totalling 108 yugas, or Ages of Man had passed on earth.

Brahma said to Kakudmi, “O King, all those whom you may have decided within the core of your heart to accept as your son-in-law have died in the course of time. Twenty-seven catur-yugas have already passed. Those upon whom you may have already decided are now gone, and so are their sons, grandsons and other descendants. You cannot even hear about their names.

You must therefore bestow your daughter upon some other husband, for you are now alone, and your friends, your ministers, servants, wives, kinsmen, armies, and treasures, have long since been swept away by the hand of time.”

King Kakudmi was astonished on hearing this news.

However, Brahma comforted him, and added that Vishnu, the preserver, was currently incarnate on earth in the forms of Krishna and Balarama, and he recommended Balarama as a worthy husband for Revati.

Kakudmi and Revati then returned to earth, which they regarded as having left only just a short while ago. They were shocked by the changes that had taken place. Not only had the landscape and environment changed, but over the intervening 27 chaturyugas (mahayugas), in the cycles of human spiritual and cultural evolution, mankind was at a lower level of development than in their own time (see Ages of Man).
The Bhagavata Purana describes that they found the race of men had become **“dwindled in stature, reduced in vigour, and enfeebled in intellect.”**

Daughter and father found Balarama and proposed the marriage, which was accepted. Since Revati came from different time behind him, she was taller than Balarama.

So, Balaram used his plough to reduce her height according to present conditions.
Their marriage was then duly celebrated.